# Background image position (from bottom and right)

Tags: html, css, background

I need a background positioning like this:
**50px from right and 60px from the bottom**. If I put background position to right bottom, it moves to extreme right and bottom.

Here is html and css.

```css
.box {
  background-image: url(http://www.iconbeast.com/images/iconbeast-pro.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right bottom;
  height: 300px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>
    This is a box. :) :)
  </p>
</div>
```

I can't solve it, although I have been trying and searching everywhere. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change background position

```
background-position: right 50px bottom 60px;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `calc(100% - 50px)`(full `width` - `50px`) and `calc(100% - 60px)`(full `height` - `60px`).

```css
.box {
  background-image: url(http://www.iconbeast.com/images/iconbeast-pro.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: calc(100% - 50px) calc(100% - 60px);
  height: 300px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>
    This is a box. :) :)
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background-position: right 50px bottom 60px;
```

```css
.box {
  background-image: url(http://www.iconbeast.com/images/iconbeast-pro.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 50px bottom 60px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>
    This is a box. :) :)
  </p>
</div>
```